# Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

Tags: sql-server-2008

Server = SQL Server 2008

Error:

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'
>   Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
>
> conn.asp, line 3

```
<%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=xx.xx.xxx.x;Database=DBxxxxxxxxx; Uid=USRxxxxxxxxxx;Pwd=PSSxxxxxxx;"
%>
```

Comment: So did you install the provider? (SQLNCLI10, the SQL Server Native Client 10)

Comment: There are some good answers over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719422/getting-error-800a0e7a-provider-cannot-be-found-it-may-not-be-properly-install

Answer (score 0):

One solution you may try
"
Unregister and re-register "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole
DB\msdasql.dll"
using regsvr32.exe
"